# How to use complex patterns in functions?

Tags: isabelle

Here is a sample function:

```
fun divide :: "enat option ⇒ enat option ⇒ real option" where
  "divide (Some ∞) _ = None"
| "divide _ (Some ∞) = None"
| "divide _ (Some 0) = None"
| "divide (Some a) (Some b) = Some (a / b)"
| "divide _ _ = None"
```

Isabelle HOL shows me the following error:

```
Malformed definition:
Non-constructor pattern not allowed in sequential mode.
⋀uw_. divide uw_ (Some 0) = None
```

Why pattern-matching works fine for `Some ∞` and doesn't work for `Some 0`? `∞` is a constant for class `infinity` and `0` is a constant for class `zero`. What is the difference between these constants?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pattern matching with `fun` only works for constructors, which are typically generated using `datatype` and `codatatype` commands. (In fact, it suffices if they are registered as free constructors using `free_constructors`.) The extended naturals `enat` as defined in `~~/src/HOL/Library/Extended_Nat` have two such constructors registered: `∞` and `enat :: nat ⇒ enat`. So `0` is not a constructor of `enat`, but of the ordinary naturals `nat`. So if you write

```
| "divide _ (Some (enat 0)) = None"
```

instead, it will work because there are only registered constructors in the patterns.

Conversely, if your theory imports `Coinductive_Nat` from the APF entry `Coinductive`, then `enat` is registered to have the constructors `0` and `eSuc`, i.e., as if it were a codatatype. Then you can pattern-match on `0`, but you can no longer pattern match on `∞`.