# How to find constructors of a datatype?

Tags: isabelle

I'm tring to define the following functions by analogy with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45932256/how-to-use-complex-patterns-in-functions/45932488):

```
fun int_divide :: "int option ⇒ int option ⇒ real option" where
  "int_divide _ (Some (int 0)) = None"
| "int_divide (Some a) (Some b) = Some (a / b)"
| "int_divide _ _ = None"

fun real_divide :: "real option ⇒ real option ⇒ real option" where
  "real_divide _ (Some (real 0)) = None"
| "real_divide (Some a) (Some b) = Some (a / b)"
| "real_divide _ _ = None"
```

But these types doesn't have `int` or `real` constructors. `int` and `real` types are defined as a `quotient_type`. And I can't find something that looks like a constructor in their theories.

The following definition doesn't work:

```
definition int0 :: "int" where
  "int0 = Abs_Integ (0,0)"

fun int_divide :: "int option ⇒ int option ⇒ real option" where
  "int_divide _ (Some int0) = None"
| "int_divide (Some a) (Some b) = Some (a / b)"
| "int_divide _ _ = None"
```

How to find all constructors for a type? Or at least for a `quotient_type`? Or how to define required constructors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not every type is built from free constructors. Sets `'a set` and reals `real` are not. One could of course show an isomorphism and declare this as a constructor, say between sets `'a set` and predicates `'a => bool`, but this will not be useful for defining functions and proving.

You can look up the registered constructors for a type using an ML block. For example, the following shows the constructors for `nat`.

```
ML ‹Ctr_Sugar.ctr_sugar_of @{context} @{type_name nat} |> Option.map #ctrs›
```

User-defined constructors can be registered using `free_constructors`, which is documented in the `tutorial on (co)datatype definitions` (available from the documentation panel).

This having been said, I do not believe that there is much point in trying to define free constructors for various number types because you would also have to prove lemmas about how all the operations on the numbers behave w.r.t. to these new constructors. This is a lot of work. It is probably easier to just use conditionals instead of pattern-matching, say

```
fun int_divide :: "int option ⇒ int option ⇒ real option" where
  "int_divide (Some a) (Some b) = (if b = 0 then None else Some (a / b))"
| "int_divide _ _ = None"
```

Another suggestion would be to avoid all the `option`s in the arguments by using the `option` monad and the function `Option.bind` for sequencing.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Andreas's answer, type definitions in Isabelle/HOL are always modulo some underlying base type. E.g. integers are defined as a quotient of pairs of natural numbers.

The typical way of defining functions on such types initially is either directly via the morphisms you get from the type definition, which convert between the underlying base type and the new type (usually something like `Abs_mytype` and `Rep_mytype`) or through `lift_definition`, which allows you to directly lift a function from the base type to the new type.

However, for library types like `int` and `real`, that is not advisable. You should not peek into the internal representation of these types but rather just use them abstractly, like you would in ‘normal’ pen-and-paper mathematics as well.